# Cakephp: How to validate array

Tags: validation, cakephp

I need to validate user thumbnail size and type  when user upload their thumbnail. But I don't know how to validate array data. So please help me

p/s: I use Cakephp 2.x

my data:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array

        (
            [id] => 45
            [username] => pa7264
            [password] => admin
            [new_password] => 
            [thumbnail] => Array
                (
                    [name] => demo.jpg
                    [type] => image/jpeg
                    [tmp_name] => D:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\phpD2FD.tmp
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 13582
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a custom validation in a pair with getimagesize() function.

Here is a quick draft for you:

```
//in User.php model
public $validate = array(
    'thumbnail' => array(
        'imageSize' => array(
            'rule' => array('check_image_size'),
            'message' => 'Thumbnail size is too big!'
        )
    )
);

// this is custom validaion function
public function check_image_size($data)
{
    $imagesize = getimagesize($data['thumbnail']['tmp_name']);
    if (($imagesize[0] > 600) || ($imagesize[1] > 400)){

        //here we taking request data to erase image to avoid problems in view
        $request = Router::getRequest();
        unset($request->data['User']['thumbnail']);
        return false; //validaion failed
    }
    return true; //validaion passed
}
```

Comment: Here $imagesize[0] is a width and $imagesize[1] is a height of an image

Comment: Thank cleverketchup, I love u so muchhhhhhhh